# Why Private Constructor works but Private Setter does not in SPRING DI IOC

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-bean

```
public class PrefixGenerator implements Generator {

    private String customDependency;

    private PrefixGenerator() {
        System.out.println("PrefixGenerator Instantiated");
    }

    private PrefixGenerator(int status) {
        System.out.println("PrefixGenerator with int arg Instantiated");
    }

    private void setCustomDependency(String customDependency) {
        this.customDependency = customDependency;
    }
}
```

Below Xml Config works

```
<bean id="bean1" class="com.hike.pojo.PrefixGenerator">
<constructor-arg name="status" value="0"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Below XML config does not Work

```
<bean id="bean2" class="com.hike.pojo.PrefixGenerator">
<property name="customDependency" value="Hmm"></property>
</bean>
```

I know, We can change Private Access Specifier using reflection.
My question is Why is Spring So designed that If Constructor is private, Spring DI works
but if Setter method is private, Spring DI does not work.

What could be Spring Designers' possible motive behind this Design ?

Why could not they allow private Setters when They allowed Private Constructor?

Comment: Constructors shouldn't be private in the first place. Private setters, however make absolutely no sense. They'd be treated simply as private methods.

Comment: @c650 Why shouldn't constructors be private?

Comment: @Kayaman Because whoever is creating an instance should have access to the constructor. In the general case, your constructors should not be private unless your class is.

Comment: @c650 That's not at all true. While generally you have non-private constructors, for example all classes with factory methods usually have a private constructor (or at least a non-public one).

Comment: @c650 We make Constructors private in case of singleton Design Pattern, Factory Pattern.
Can Anybody tell me rationale behind this Design Logic of Spring DI ?
You can tag any Spring Designer , if you want to

Comment: Spring is following the Java Beans specs for accessing properties, that specification requires that get/set be `public` to have a property (it even uses the underlying JDK implementation for it!). Without it it isn't a property. For the constructor spring needs to be able to construct a bean regardless of where it comes from or what its access level is.

Comment: Why is this question Downvoted ? It helps us to understand Internal Design intention of Spring

Answer (score 0):

Spring do not need to know about your private data member, that's why private setters are not supported.

Now coming on to the private constructor , as you said it follows the singleton design patterns. To support this spring allows you to create singleton beans.

Spring is completely based on reflection. It follows all the design principle and gives the power to the developer.